# Access private functions from private functions in Octave [BUG]

Tags: octave, private, code-organization

In Matlab private functions are those stored in subdirectories with the name **private**. They have a restriction of visibility that: "*you cannot call the private function from the command line or from functions outside the parent of the private folder*" (https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html).

EDIT: Octave tries to follow this: "if the path to **func1** is **directory/func1.m**, and if **func2** is found in the directory **directory/private/func2.m**, then **func2** is only available for use of the functions, like **func1**, that are found in **directory**." (https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Private-Functions.html)

I'm using Octave 6.2.

I have a couple of functions that I want to make private, say **A** and **B**. They have some common part, so it is natural to separate out this part and create another function, say **C**, to be called from interiors of **A** and **B**.

I placed **C** in the same private directory as **A** and **B**, and it seems that this construction is not allowed by the language, as I get an error saying that **C** is undefined. I find it counterintuitive, nonetheless, this could be expected according to the above quote from documentation of Octave, saying that private functions are visible only from the *parent* directory.

I tried placing a nested private subdirectory within the first one (with the relative path "**private/private**") as a workaround, but it doesn't solve the problem, and I still get an error with undefined **C**.

Thus, the only way to call **C** from private **A** and **B** seems to be to make it publicly visible, even though from the code architecture point of view **C** *should not be public*, since it is called only by private functions. Another way would be to keep copies of the same code of **C** within both **A** and **B** - with all bad consequences of the violation of the DRY principle.

EDIT: As indicated in the comments this problem seems to be Octave specific. In Matlab you can access private functions from other private functions.

My question is: *What is the proper way of maintaining common parts of private functions in Octave?*

EDIT2: The problem indeed seems to be a **bug** in the current version of Octave. The MWE provided by [carandraug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67338703/8751875) works fine *unless*...

I found that the following sequence is a mininal-**not** working-example making the bug *explicit*:
1)
**A.m** and **C.m** are in the **directory**, **A.m** calls **B.m**.
**B.m** is in **directory/private**, initially *NOT* calling **C.m**.
Evaluation of **A** works fine.
2)
Modify **B.m** to call **C**.
Evaluation of **A** still works fine.
3)
Move **C.m** to **private**.
Evaluation of **A** *returns error* with **C** undefined.

On the other hand the following sequence (the one occurring in most situations) *doesn't reveal* the error:
1')
**A.m** and **C.m** in **directory**, **A.m** calls **B.m**. **B.m** is in **private**, this time *calling* **C.m**
Evaluation of **A** works fine.
3')
Move **C.m** to **private**.
Evaluation of **A** still works *fine*.

So, step 2) for some reason is crutial for the bug to occur.

EDIT3: For fresh Octave from GUI this is how it works for me (on Windows 10 Pro 20H2, maybe this matters):

```
>> cd C:\Octave\test\
>> ls
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\Octave\test

[.]       [..]      A.m       C.m       [private]
               2 File(s)            101 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  129 967 509 504 bytes free
>> A
this is A
this is B
>> % now edit B to call C
>> A
this is A
this is B
this is C
>> movefile("C.m", "private/C.m")
ans = 1
>> A
this is A
this is B
error: 'C' undefined near line 3, column 3
error: called from
    B at line 3 column 3
    A at line 3 column 3
```

Comment: "but I expect compatibility on this is achieved in both implementations of the language" not a general rule, FYI.

Comment: I agree, Matlab and Octave are not fully compatible, but knowing if this is a compatibility issue would also be very useful for me.

Comment: In MATLAB you can call a private function from another private function in the same private directory.  Even if the documentation is poorly worded in this respect.

Comment: Thank you very much! So my question is specifically Octave, I'll edit it.

Comment: It appears that you have found a bug in Octave. You may report the bug   to Octave bug tracker.

Comment: @PiotrM I have followed your steps and I'm unable to reproduce the bug. The steps you describe work fine. You do not specify if you restart your octave session after each redefinition or not. If not, and this is the cause of your 'bug', then note that this is intentional for the sake of optimisations. See the [ignore_function_timestamp function](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Function-Files.html#index-ignore_005ffunction_005ftime_005fstamp) for details.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I have added some more details to my post.

Comment: @PiotrM Yes, this confirms my point. This is simply a side-effect of you having changed the function definition while still in the same session. Octave will not re-compile files it has already compiled, unless you explicitly ask it to, e.g. using `clear functions` (alternatively you can simply restart your octave session). This is a feature, not a bug. Many other languages work the same way (python, for example).

Comment: i believe we have seen other examples where octave fails to notice a change to a function until a restart, when we are expecting otherwise.  I'd have to dig out the report, but in one case i think this was related to a network drive not updating the Modified Date property. in this case, the ignore_function_timestamp setting shouldn't matter because it's not under `octave-home/share/version/m`, correct?  something in a working folder should immediately see the change, no?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed `clear functions` solves the problem. But using `ignore_function_time_stamp ('none')` doesn't. IMHO this behaviour that Octave is neither able to use the old compiled version nor re-compile for the new version, is counter-intuitive. But I'm happy that the issue has been clarified. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you suggest should work in Octave so I believe your error is elsewhere. Can you provide a minimal example of how it is not working? Here's mine working in Octave:

```
$ cat dd/A.m 
function A ()
  disp('this is A')
  B()
endfunction

$ cat dd/private/B.m 
function B ()
  disp('this is B')
  C()
endfunction

$ cat dd/private/C.m
function C ()
  disp('this is C')
endfunction

$ octave --path 'dd' --eval 'A()'
this is A
this is B
this is C
```